# Delegate is not calling method

Tags: objective-c, ios, objective-c-protocol

So i have a question .
Can someone Tell me the Problem with this line of code for calling(protocol) a Method

```
 [self.delegate poplogin];
```

poplogin is method name , its not working for some reason.
its not calling the method poplogin

for reference :

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) id<loginAuthDelegate> delegate;
```

So let me Explain the Case

so lets say i have a Class abc.h

```
@protocol loginAuthDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)poplogin;
@end
```

After interface

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) id<loginAuthDelegate> delegate;

in .m i am just calling the Delegate and @synthesize it
[self.delegate poplogin];

not i have another files
let say def.h
i am importing the Class abc.h
@interface def : UIViewController<loginAuthDelegate>



def.m
-(void)poplogin
{
NSLog(@"Delegate doesn't respond to here");
vmpaSecureLogin *ivc = [[vmpaSecureLogin alloc] init];
ivc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
[self presentModalViewController:ivc animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: are you sure delegate is not nil?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably because `self.delegate` is `nil`.

You probably forgot to affect your object's `delegate` to some other object in which you implemented the delegate methods, like your ViewController or something.

Comment: So you just confirmed that what I explain is the cause of your problem: in your code your wrote in your question, you never assign the delegate property to a value (i.e. `abcInstance.delegate = defInstance;`) so of course the value of your `delegate` property is `nil` — and sending a message to `nil` (as in `[self.delegate poplogin]` when `self.delegate` is `nil`) won't do anything

Comment: Could you please suggest where to write that in the Code . or if you give me a better Example on this

Comment: I don't have your code where you create the `abc` instance and can't guess. But that exactly the same as every usage of a delegate (for a tableview, a textview, a textfield, or every time you use delegates). When you create your instance `abcObject` of class `abc`, probably in your `defObject` instance of your `def` class, set `abcObject.delegate = defObject` so that the `def` object becomes the delegate of `abc` object and will receive its messages. No magic here.